# Integration by Partial Fraction Decomposition, Given Arbitrary Constants

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

Given Newton's 2nd law equation, I'm supposed to find $v$. My second law equation is:  $m\dot{v}=-bv-vc^2$

By separation of variables, I arrive at
$$\frac{dv}{bv+cv^2}=\frac{-1}{m}dt$$

$$\int_{v_0}^{v}\frac{dv}{bv+cv^2}=\frac{-1}{m}\int_0^tdt$$

To solve my integral on the left, my professor told us that partial fraction decomp will be the easiest way of solving.
$$\frac{1}{v(b+cv)}=\frac{A}{v}+\frac{B}{b+cv}$$

$$1=A(b+cv)+B(v)$$
I believe I can find one of the numerators by setting $v=0$, that is: $$1=A(b+c\cdot0)+B(0)$$

$$1=Ab$$

$$\therefore A=\frac{1}{b}$$

I can also make $v=\frac{1}{c}$ (assuming this is allowed), in which case:

$$1=A(b+c\cdot\frac{1}{c})+B(\frac{1}{c})$$

$$1=\frac{1}{b}(b+1)+\frac{B}{c}$$

$$1=1+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{B}{c}$$

$$\therefore B=-\frac{c}{b}$$

My integral can now be written as:

$$\int_{v_0}^{v}\frac{dv}{bv+cv^2}=\frac{1}{b}\int_{v_0}^v\frac{1}{v}-\frac{c}{b+cv}dv$$

In which case my solution is

$$\frac{1}{b}[\ln{v}-\ln{(b+cv)}]|_{v_0}^v$$

I want to confirm my work, as I didn't start making progress on the problem until my professor was no longer available, and my other classmates are also confused.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: I think it is correct till now. You just need to evaluate the boundary terms and exponentiate both sides.